# Web Api asp.net mvc tem algum limite de dados informado no Route?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma web api, estou tentando fazer uma inserção em um cadastro de usuário, mais observei que o número de parâmetros tem um limite. Se eu tentar adicionar um parâmetro a mais gera um erro:

```
      [HttpPost]
        [Route("consulta/InseriUsuario/{apiKey}/{userKey}/{idpais}/{idioma}/{idperfil}/{nomecompleto}/{sobrenome}/{titulocareira}/{ladoequipe}/{patrocinador}/{email}/{celular}/{cidade}/{endereco}/{cep}/{uf}/{numero}/{complemento}/{senha}/{login}/{nomeequipe}/{ddi_fone}/{ddd_fone}/{telefone}/{ddi_whtas}/{ddd_whats}/{whatsapp}/{skype}/{twitter}")]

        public  HttpResponseMessage InseriUsuario(string apiKey, string userKey, int IDPAIS, int IDIDIOMA, int IDPERFIL, string NOMECOMPLETO, string SOBRENOME,
                                 string TITULOCARREIRA, string LADOEQUIPE, string PATROCINADOR, string EMAIL,
                                 string CELULAR, string CIDADE, string ENDERECO, string CEP,
                                 string UF, string NUMERO, string COMPLEMENTO, string SENHA,
                                 string LOGIN, string NOMEEQUIPE, string DDI_FONE, string DDD_FONE,
                                 string TELEFONE, string DDI_WHATS, string DDD_WHATS, string WHATSAPP,
                                 string SKYPE, string TWITTER, string FACEBOOK, string URLCADASTRO,
                                 string URLCONFERENCIA, string HORACONFERENCIA, string URLCONFERENCIAGRAVADA, string URLLOJAVIRTUAL,
                                 string TITULODEPOIMENTO, string DESCRICAODEPOIMENTO, string IMAGEMPERFIL)
        {

            try
            {
                var tTabela = new UsuarioAplicacao();
                tTabela.InseriUsuario(apiKey, userKey, IDPAIS, IDIDIOMA, IDPERFIL, NOMECOMPLETO, SOBRENOME, TITULOCARREIRA, LADOEQUIPE,
                                        PATROCINADOR, EMAIL, CELULAR, CIDADE, ENDERECO, CEP, UF, NUMERO, COMPLEMENTO, SENHA, LOGIN, NOMEEQUIPE,
                                        DDI_FONE, DDD_FONE, TELEFONE, DDD_WHATS, DDD_WHATS, WHATSAPP, SKYPE, TWITTER, FACEBOOK, URLCADASTRO,
                                        URLCONFERENCIA, HORACONFERENCIA, URLCONFERENCIAGRAVADA, URLLOJAVIRTUAL, TITULODEPOIMENTO,
                                        DESCRICAODEPOIMENTO, IMAGEMPERFIL);

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, tTabela);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: você pode transformar todos esses parâmetros em um objeto só

Comment: @EduardoSampaio, tem como postar um exemplo mais detalhado, agradeço

Answer (score 0):

objeto

```
public class ClientViewModelRegister
{      
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}



        [HttpPost]
        [Route("register")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Register(ClientViewModelRegister model)
        {

            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    Client client = new Client()
                    {
                        Name = model.Name,
                        Email = model.Email,
                        DateRegister = DateTime.Today                                                  
                    };

                    _AppClient.Insert(client);

                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Register Successfully");

                }
                else
                {
                    return ErrorModel();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e.Message);
            }

        }
```

primeiro temos objeto segundo o controller você tem fazer desta maneira  onde que estão propriedade, você coloca tudo em objeto que deseja receber como parâmetro assim fica mais simples,vou deixar link de um projeto abaixo para você ter como exemplo.
https://github.com/EduardoSampaio/Gerenciamento.api/blob/master/Gerenciamento.Api/Controllers/ClientController.cs

obs: toda chamada que fizer nome quando enviar deve ser igual da propriedade se não ira receber valor nulo.

ex: se eu envio um nome
objeto deve ter propriedade 
public string nome {get;set;}